# PySpark convert a ByteArray to Double in a dataFrame

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, dataframe, type-conversion

i have a little table with a ByteArray field

```
spark.sql("select ech_montant, ech_piece from f_echeances where ech_piece = 'FHTL0140'").show()
+----------------+---------+
|     ech_montant|ech_piece|
+----------------+---------+
|[01 4D 4A 92 20]| FHTL0140|
+----------------+---------+
```

I'm trying to convert the bytes "on the fly" to their original value (numeric(24,6) or double)

I have tried this :

```
import struct
spark.udf.register('todouble', lambda x: struct.unpack('d', x))
spark.sql("select ech_montant, todouble(ech_montant), ech_piece from f_echeances where ech_piece = 'FHTL0140'").show()
```

But it fails with the error

```
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 8
```

Is there another way to proceed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution

```
spark.udf.register('ByteArrayToDouble', lambda x: int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='big', signed=False)
spark.sql("select ByteArrayToDouble(ech_montant) from f_echeances where ech_piece = 'FHTL0140'").show()

+------------------------------+                                                
|ByteArrayToDouble(ech_montant)|
+------------------------------+
|                   55917000000|
+------------------------------+
```